# For Loop + Concatenate

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, concatenation

I am want to select a table and concatenate its content into one cell. 
I was thinking to use a For loop but I lack a function that will purely concatenate the values of a range of cells, a function that will allow the use of variables (for my "for loop").

Here is a draft of what I would like to do, it misses a lot of things but without this mysterious function, I could not go really far...

```
xCol = Selection.Columns.Count
xRow = Selection.Rows.Count
Range("A13").Select

Row = 1
    For Row = 1 To xRow
        For i = 1 To xCol
          ActiveCell.value = FUNCTION Cells(Row, i)
        Next
    Next
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Eñaut: So if I try to understand, you want to concatenate the value of a column lines into a single cell? Is that right?

Comment: `=TEXTJOIN()`? Built in commands are better to use. If you are not using a version of Excel that includes that particular formula, you can easily build it yourself. Once you have done that, or if you have any particular questions in doing so, then you can come here and ask that specific question.

Comment: My guess is that you would be interested in the `Join` function. If you able to understand and use the `Evaluate` method along with that, it would prevent a loop through an entire range. I also do agree with the `TEXTJOIN` function if you got the right version of Excel and avoid VBA alltogether

Comment: Btw, you should try avoid selection of cells and refer to them directly.. there should be easy to find information on the web and SO if you give it a search

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main question is why you are using VBA for this: as mentioned in some comments, you can use the worksheet functions `CONCAT` and `TEXTJOIN` for the same purpose. (`CONCAT` just glues cell values together, while `TEXTJOIN` gives some more possibilities, like a separator between the concatenated values)